# actionlink should not submit if the check box was not checked

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i was set action link asp.net mvc grid.
like below.
when click on action link it is going to javascript function,
there i was set return false ,this false for page should not submit to action.
but cursor is going controler correspond action.
how to prevent this.
if check box was not checked only popup raise and page should not submited to action.

below is my code function actionlink:

```
 grid.Column("Title",
 format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink((string)item.Title,
"Details", "Home", new { id = item.ID }, new { onclick = "getValueUsingClass1()" })</text>),





   function getValueUsingClass1() { debugger;
 $(".myCssClass:checked").each(function ()
 { chkArray.push($(this).val());
     var selected; 
    selected = chkArray.join(',') + ","; 
   if (selected.length > 1)
    { alert("You have selected " + selected); } 
   else { alert("Please at least one of the checkbox"); } 
  return false;
 }); 
}
```

Comment: please show getValueUsingClass1() and format code

Answer (score 0):

To return from function you can use `return false` or `e.preventDefault()`. You have returned from `.each` function take that statement outside `.each` or use `e.preventDefault()`

```
grid.Column("Title",
 format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink((string)item.Title,
"Details", "Home", new { id = item.ID }, new { onclick = "getValueUsingClass1(event)" }


 function getValueUsingClass1(e) { debugger;
 $(".myCssClass:checked").each(function (){

     chkArray.push($(this).val());
     var selected; 
     selected = chkArray.join(',') + ","; 
     if (selected.length > 1)
         { 
alert("You have selected " + selected);
 } 
     else { alert("Please at least one of the checkbox"); } 


 }); 
e.preventDefault();
//OR
return false;
}
```

Comment: HI nitin,i had done as per your code,but form was submitted to action.

Comment: have u debugged in browser, is javascript function called?

Comment: yes, debugged but cursor is called the action method.or tell me is there any other alternate method.

Comment: Hi nitin,when we are using the db first , do we have to all way generate poco classes by using right click on add codegeneration item.when ever if change the dbschema we to do autocodegeneration? please conform me this.